# Why is Jon's surname Snow if he was born outside the North?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In Westeros, usually, bastards' surnames depend on the land where they were born. For example, Robert Baratheon's bastards are Edric Storm and Mya Stone. **So, why is Jon's surname Snow?**

There are a lot of in-universe and out-universe theories

> and even on-screen confirmation of Rhaegar+Lyanna

but all of them says that Jon was born outside of the North.

Update:
Proof of why Jon was not born in the North; Robb is a little bit older than Jon. Ned married Catelyn in Riverrun, conceived Robb and went South to fight in Robert's rebellion. There, in just a couple of months, somebody (maybe Ned, maybe not) conceived and then a woman gave birth to Jon.

Comment: No source but would be a lot to do with Ned taking him home and naming him as such

Comment: He was raised in the North, by Northerners. Where he was born isn't that important, plus it was probably meant to be a secret.

Answer (score 16):

Remember, Ned is claiming that Jon is his own child. While he was physically born outside of the North, he was brought to live in the North by a Northman. It has more to do with who the bastard was born to and where they live then where they are actually born.

[Explanation of Bastard Naming:](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bastardy#Surnames)

> Each of the nine constituent regions of the Seven Kingdoms have bastard surnames **decreed by custom, not law.** Bastards with a high-born parent are given these surnames to hold them **apart from their fathers' houses**. The parents may give a bastard a different surname if they wish, e.g. Tyrion Tanner. Bastards with no known relation to a noble house have no surname, like other smallfolk.

Examples of bastard naming:

> The surname a bastard received appears to be **connected to the location the child is raised,** though this is not a consistent rule. Because of this, bastards who are half-siblings might have different surnames. For example, King Robert I Baratheon's eldest bastard, born in the Vale, is called Mya Stone, while his bastard from the Stormlands (fathered on a noblewoman from the Reach) is called Edric Storm. However, whilst Aegor Rivers was raised at Stone Hedge in the Riverlands, his half-brother Brynden, was also called Rivers, despite having lived at least the first few years of his life with his mother at King's Landing in the Crownlands.

Update for Season 7, Episode 7:

Bran states to Sam that Jon was never a Snow at all, that bastards born in Dorne are called Sand. How much of this is just Bran's opinion is not really known

Comment: Besides which, disguising the boy's origin was pretty much the goal of claiming him as a bastard in the first place.  As such, he might have lied about where, exactly, the boy was born, as well... I mean, which would divert suspicion more? "I coincidentally found him in the place where Rhaegar died!" or "I had an affair with a Northern girl, and on the way home from the campaign she presented me with a bastard."

Comment: Never noticed Mya Stone and Edric Storm surnaming. Maybe, it is due to the fact that Edric Storm is an acknowledged bastard while Mya Stone is not.

Comment: I think she was at least recognized, because otherwise she would not have a bastard name... like Gendry

Comment: @Skooba, Cotter Pyke was a bastard of a tavern wench. I guess Gendry is an oversight.

Comment: @starpilotsix it could not be an affair with a Northern girl because Ned married Katelyn in Riverrun, conceived Robb and went to the South. There somebody conceived and gave a birth to Jon

Comment: @Schullz Ah, fair enough, I wasn't 100% clear on the timeline, but, even so, naming him "Snow" makes people less likely to look into all the fine details, because of the perception that Snow = Northern Kid

Comment: @c.koca IIRC Mya Stone is acknowledged as well. Don't we hear that Robert visited her in the books?

Comment: @kuhl do we? I guess I missed that part.

Comment: @C.Koca I might be misremembering, but I thought Mya had met Robert.  Now I'm second guessing myself :)  I'll need to take a look at that chapter again at some point.

Comment: @kuhl it is a very small detail, so I might easily have missed that as well :)

Comment: [Mya Stone vs Gendry](http://asoiafuniversity.tumblr.com/post/78140918316/if-mya-stone-is-an-acknowledged-bastard-then-why): "He’s not taking responsibility, but everyone knows. So why wouldn’t she be a Stone? Everyone knows she’s the daughter of a king. This isn’t like Gendry where he’s 100% clueless and never met his father (nor does Robert know of him to our knowledge.)"

Comment: @starpilotsix Just a point of correction, Rhaegar died by Roberts hand at the Battle of the Trident, no where near where Lyanna gave birth. I'm also pretty sure that Jon's "origin" by some woman in the South is well known around Winterfell.

Comment: And, along those lines, Ned may have claimed that he was born in the North, a product of wenching before he reached the south.  I'd have to go back and look at timelines for where he was about nine months before the war wrapped up.  Even if Ned went South to war after marrying, at some point he might have gone north to muster his army.

Comment: @C.Koca you are correct. There's a line in AFFC that explicitly says that her father did not acknowledge her.

Comment: BCDotWeb is correct. While Robert never acknowledged any bastard except Edric Storm, he was very fond of his first born daughter Mya. He used to spend a lot of time with her when she was a kid. He even wanted to bring her to the court in KL but backed down after Cersei's threats against her. Everyone in Vale knows that Mya is a noble bastard. Thus she gets the name stone without official recognition from her father. No one except three men knew Gendry's father so he does not get a noble bastard surname.

Comment: @AndrewMattson if Ned conceived Jon with Northern girl before arriving in the South, he did not visit Riverrun yet, and wasn't married. So, wenching with girls was not infidelity, he was a free man. But it was said sometimes that Ned's affair was an infidelity. Also, Jon is younger that Rob

Comment: @Schultz - obviously, I wasn't claiming that it happened, I was speculating on possible "plausible deniability," but, as I said, I needed to check the timelines.  You are right, but it's really irrelevant (because my speculation is irrelevant) because Ned never gave a story about who the mother was or what happened, at all.  Snow is Snow because he was raised by Starks at Winterfell, I guess.